# Python comparing input to line in file?

Tags: python, file, input, compare

My name is Seix_Seix, and I have a doubt about a program in Python that I am building.

The thing is, that I'm doing a "riddle game" *(silly, right?)*, to practise some basical Python skills. The intended flow of the program is that you give it a number from 1 to 5, and then it open a file with all the riddles stored in it, and it prints the one in the line of the number you gave.
Afterwards, it asks you for an input, in which you type the answer, and then **(this is where all crumbled down)** it compares your answer to the corresponding line on **another** file *(where all the answers are)*.

Here is the code so you can give it a look *(It's in spanish since it's my mother language, but it also has a translation and explanation in the comments)

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

f = open ("C:\Users\Public\oo.txt", "r") #This is where all the riddles are stored, each one in a separate line
g = open ("C:\Users\Public\ee.txt", "r") #This is where the answers to the riddles are, each one in the same line as its riddle
ques=f.readlines()
ans=g.readlines()

print "¡Juguemos a las adivinanzas!" #"Lets play a riddle game!"
guess = int(raw_input("Escoge un número entre 1 y 5. O puedes tirar los dados(0) ")) #"Choose a number from 1 to 5, or you can roll the dice (0)" #This is the numerical input, in which you choose the riddle

if guess==0:
    import random
    raw_input(random.randrange(1, 5))

print (ques[guess-1]) #Here, it prints the line corresponding to the number you gave, minus 1 (because the first line is 0, the second one is 1 and so on)
a=input("¿Sabes qué es?") #"Do you know the answer?" #Here, you are supposed to type the answer to the riddle.

while True:
    if a==(ans[guess-1]): #And here, it is supposed to compare the answer you gave with the corresponding line on the answer file (ee.txt). 
        print "ok" #If you are correct it congratulates you, and breaks the loop.
        break
    else:
        print "no" #If you are wrong, it repeats its question over and over again
```

And so, I run the program. Everything is fine for a while until the moment when I have to input the answer; there, no matter what I put, even if it's right or wrong, it gives me the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[User]\Desktop\lol.py", line 16, in <module>
    a=input("¿Sabes qué es?") #"Do you know the answer?" #Here, you are supposed to type the answer to the riddle.
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'aguacate' is not defined #It is the correct answer BTW
```

I **know** this problem generates when it starts to compare the answers, and I also **KNOW** that it's probably because I wrote it wrong... Sooo, any advice on how to do it right?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, or Python will try to evaluate the entered string - and since `aguacate` is not an expression that Python knows, it throws the Exception you found.

Also, your "throw the dice" routine doesn't work (try entering `0` and see what happens). That should be

```
if guess == 0:
    # import random should be at the start of the script
    guess = random.randrange(1,6)
```

---

Some other comments about your code, as requested:

In general, it's quite OK. There are a few little things that you can optimize:

You're not closing the files you have opened. That's not a problem when you're only reading them, but it will cause problems once you start writing files. Better to get used to that quickly. The best way for this is to use a `with` statement block; that will automatically take care of closing your file, even if an exception occurs during the execution of your program:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Public\oo.txt") as f, open(r"C:\Users\Public\ee.txt") as g:
    ques = f.readlines()
    ans = g.readlines()
```

Note that I used raw strings (important if you have backslashes in your strings). If you had named your file `tt.txt`, your version would have failed because it would have looked for a file named `Public<tab>t.txt` because the `\t` would have been interpreted as a tab character.

Also, take a moment to study [PEP-8, the Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It will help you write more readable code.

Since you're using Python 2, you can drop the parentheses in `print (ques[guess-1])` (or switch to Python 3, which I would recommend anyway because Unicode! Also, in Python 3, `raw_input()` has finally been renamed as `input()`).

Then, I think you need to strip off the trailing newline character from your answer strings, or they won't compare correctly (also, drop the unnecessary parentheses):

```
if a == ans[guess-1].rstrip("\n"):
```

Comment: Sweet mother of... It actually worked! I feel really, **REALLY** dumb right now...¬¬


But seriously though, thank you **VERY MUCH**.


And sorry about the dice part, I was so focused on solving the comparison problem that I completely forgot about it...


Oh! One more thing... Could you give me your opinion about the code in general? I'm a complete n00b here, so I could use all the feedback I could get...


Thanks again,
Seix_Seix

Comment: @Seix_Seix: Sure, I have edited my answer. I hope you'll enjoy StackOverflow as much as I do. You might also want to take a moment to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), that will help you get started even better (without a risk of upsetting some of the more cantankerous oldtimers here) :)